# .htaccess changes to move site to SSL/https

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Those are the lines of concern currently in my .htaccess file,
note that i have two domains pointing to the same site:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2\.com$ [NC]     
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Now I need to convert my site to SSL, I was instructed to use the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I think that this code misses my other domain and the www rewrite part,
how to enable SSL while accounting for my other domain and also for the WWW part?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example2\.com$ [NC]     
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much,
should i just add those lines as they are right below
 RewriteEngine On
without deleting old lines?

Comment: Only those lines as they are right below (I add  RewriteEngine On)

Comment: Hi i added them but i can't access the admin pages now for some reason, normal pages are running normally  www.example.com/admin

Comment: i appended this line, please tell mei if that's ok, i can access now   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin

Comment: Why? You can't use admin with ssl and www ?

Comment: no it keeps redirecting forever, here is the current code: 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^2knowmyself\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?toknowmyself\.com$ [NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.2knowmyself.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]